# Solr : Issues with Soft Auto commit (Near Real Time)

Tags: solr, solr4j

Having issues in Soft Auto commit (Near Real Time). Am using solr 4.3 on tomcat . The **index size is 10.95 GB**. With this configuration it **takes more than 60 seconds to return the indexed document.** When adding documents to solr and searching after soft commit time, its returning 0 hits. Its taking long before the document actually starts showing up, **even more than the autoCommit interval**.

```
 <autoCommit> 
   <maxTime>15000</maxTime> 
   <openSearcher>false</openSearcher> 
 </autoCommit>

   <autoSoftCommit> 
     <maxTime>1000</maxTime> 
   </autoSoftCommit>
```

Machine is ubuntu 13 / 4 cores / 16GB RAM. Given 6gb to Solr running over tomcat.

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding new document using solr client, try using commitWithin, its more flexible over autoSoftCommit.One more thing make sure the u have update log is enabled in solrconfig.xml and get handler as well.You can get more details here-http://wiki.apache.org/solr/NearRealtimeSearch